# Change colors of each disk in a geographic Map with Mathematica

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to change the color of the bubbles. I have created the variable to contain the colors instead of the values

```
colorME = ReplaceAll[GhanaMalariaData[[All, 3]], monthRule]
```

but I cannot figure out how to represent it in the graph.

```
v = ghanaMalariaPositive/ Max[Sort[ghanaMalariaPositive]] * 50; 
y = MapThread[List, {latLog, v}];
x =MapThread[ GeoDisk[#1, Quantity[#2,"Kilometers"]]&, {latLog, v}];
GeoGraphics[{Polygon[Ghana (country)], {Red,x}}, Frame->True, GeoRange->Ghana (country)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here how to do it:
We have the 12 months of the year, and we want to see if location of Malaria 
change through the time of the year

```
colorRule = RandomColor[12]
monthRule = Table[Rule[i, colorRule[[i]]], {i, 12}]
colorME = ReplaceAll[data[[All, 3]], monthRule]
coloring = Flatten[MapThread[List[#1, #2] &, {colorME, x}]]
GeoGraphics[{Polygon[Ghana  (country)],coloring},Frame->True,GeoRange->Ghana       (country)]
```

[image]